# VASP jobs crashing - VASP 5.4.4

Tags: vasp

I have been trying to generate potential energy curves with doing single point calculations with VASP - 5.4.4
many of my jobs crash or stay stuck on a single line until it runs out of time. can some one please help me out with this?.
I have attached the errors I am getting, along with a submit script that i used to submit the jobs.

error 1 - this hasn't gone past the line "
The following have been reloaded with a version change: "distr:  one band on    4 cores,   15 groups"

```
1) compiler/intel/18 => compiler/intel/19     2) intel-mpi/18 => intel-mpi/19

Starting Time is Tue Aug 22 13:43:59 CDT 2023
 running on   60 total cores
 distrk:  each k-point on   60 cores,    1 groups
 distr:  one band on    4 cores,   15 groups
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 50226784 ON r05r20n04 CANCELLED AT 2023-08-22T19:44:10 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 50226784.0 ON r05r20n04 CANCELLED AT 2023-08-22T19:44:10 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

error 2 - I do not know what this means

```
 LDA part: xc-table for Pade appr. of Perdew
 POSCAR, INCAR and KPOINTS ok, starting setup
Abort(674835087) on node 54 (rank 54 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Alltoallv: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Alltoallv(391)................: MPI_Alltoallv(sbuf=0x2acbbe05e020, scnts=0xb2bf480, sdispls=0xb2bf220, MPI_INTEGER, rbuf=0x2acbbe476020, rcnts=0xb2bf820, rdispls=0xb2bf5c0, datatype=MPI_INTEGER, comm=comm=0xc4000000) failed
MPIDI_SHMGR_Gather_generic(1051)...:
MPIDI_NM_mpi_alltoallv(850)........:
MPIR_Alltoallv_intra_scattered(123):
MPIR_Waitall(184)..................:
MPIR_Waitall_impl(59)..............:
MPIDI_Progress_test(183)...........:
MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error(1077)....: OFI poll failed (ofi_events.h:1077:MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error:Input/output error)
Abort(3746447) on node 59 (rank 59 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Alltoallv: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Alltoallv(391)................: MPI_Alltoallv(sbuf=0x2ad673c9e020, scnts=0xc49cd40, sdispls=0xc49cae0, MPI_INTEGER, rbuf=0x2ad6740b6020, rcnts=0xc49d0c0, rdispls=0xc49ce60, datatype=MPI_INTEGER, comm=comm=0xc4000000) failed
MPIDI_SHMGR_Gather_generic(1051)...:
MPIDI_NM_mpi_alltoallv(850)........:
MPIR_Alltoallv_intra_scattered(123):
MPIR_Waitall(184)..................:
MPIR_Waitall_impl(59)..............:
MPIDI_Progress_test(183)...........:
MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error(1077)....: OFI poll failed (ofi_events.h:1077:MPIDI_OFI_handle_cq_error:Input/output error)
```

the submit script

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --job-name=or2nod3
#SBATCH --nodes=3
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=20
#SBATCH --time=00-06:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=12gb
#SBATCH --output=vasp_runex.log
#SBATCH --partition=sixhour
#SBATCH --constraint=ib

# convert the file convert_1.py using the distance value
module load python
sed -i "s/XX/8.0/g" convert_1.py
python convert_1.py
cp POSCAR ./inputs/

# We load all the default program system settings with module load:
module purge
module load compiler/intel/18
module load intel-mpi/18
module load vasp/5.4.4

proj=inputs # Name of job folder
input=$(ls ${proj}/{INCAR,POTCAR,POSCAR,KPOINTS}) # Input files from job folder

echo Starting Time is `date`
export VASP_WORKDIR=/home/$USER/scratch/orient_2/no_disp/slab_8.0

mkdir -p $VASP_WORKDIR

# Preparing and moving inputfiles to tmp:

submitdir=$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

cp $input $VASP_WORKDIR
cd $VASP_WORKDIR

######################################
# Section for running the program and cleaning up:

# Running the program:
time mpirun vasp_std

# Investigate potentially other files to keep:
echo $(pwd)
echo $(ls -ltr)

# ALWAYS clean up after yourself. Please do uncomment the following line
# If we have to, we get really grumpy!
#cd $submitdir
#rm -r $VASP_WORKDIR/*

echo "Job finished at"
exit 0
```

any help to resolve these are appreciated.